# Compiling GUIs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compilation, matlab-guide

I have developed a software based on GUIDE of MATLAB containing 15 windows and each window open by pressing a button. I have 15 `.m` files and 15 `.fig` files respectively. I want to compile it as a standalone exe. However, on compiler tool, at the first field, it is asked to insert a main file and at another field the required files in order to run my application. At first field I can import only one file. At the other filed I can import as many files as I want. Doing like this, leads to an application that runs only the first window. How I should compile it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to utilize a "main.m" file where it calls each of the other m-files. It does not need to be named main.m, but that is what a lot of people would call it. Similar to C programming where you typically have a main() function encapsulating the entire program (at least in the beginning - I am not an expert at C)

[Here is an image to hopefully clear up what I mean a bit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9XA7.png)

Comment: Thank you very much foryour help!!!My problem is that I want each figure to lead to next figure, not to run all simultaneously. Imagine, like a setup wizard in which you press next button and another window is presented. I would something like this. So I created buttons at each figure and when you press it, sets the current figure visible off and runs the next figure. So, I inserted as main file the first m file for the first figure and as additional files all the others. Should I define the path of the files each time that I use the button?

Comment: Wow, sorry I didn't realize you had commented on my answer; sorry for the delay. I'm not sure exactly how you would go about doing what you are describing (if I am envisioning it correctly). If you still haven't worked something out for this, maybe a bit clearer explanation with some pictures or markups might be helpful.